# Reading the Output In the Eclipse Console In RIDE

Tags: robotframework

How can I validate the Response from an mock aggregator that is coming to my Eclipse Console in RIDE/Robot Framework.

Comment: It Is an asynchronous service, I am calling the Post Rest Service that returns me with some response.
And Then I am even Getting a Response Back from the Mock Aggregator in the Eclipse Console, that contains some part of the response from the Rest Service., and that is what I need to validate

Comment: You may edit your question at any time, SK. There's no need to add extra info in comments.